# Assembly Analysis Tools

Tags: gcc, assembly, code-analysis, llvm

Does anyone have any suggestions for assembly file analysis tools? I'm attempting to analyze ARM/Thumb-2 ASM files generated by LLVM (or alternatively GCC) when passed the -S option. I'm particularly interested in instruction statistics at the basic block level, e.g. memory operation counts, etc. I may wind up rolling my own tool in Python, but was curious to see if there were any existing tools before I started.

Update: I've done a little searching, and found a good resource for disassembly tools / hex editors / etc [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Analysis_Tools), but unfortunately it is mainly focused on x86 assembly, and also doesn't include any actual assembly file analyzers.

Comment: Methinks analysing the LLVM IR would be easier since it uses SSA form for the registers.

Comment: @delnan I agree, but I'm adding an assembly-level optimization pass, so I need to be able to analyze the actual generated ASM.

Comment: might I suggest that your pass work either as an LLVM MachineFunctionPass or if absolutely necessary inside the MC infrastructure?  There's really no reason to parse asm, rebuild all the control and data flow information, and then do some optimization.

Comment: @ohmantics: This analysis is done after the new optimization is run. The actual implementation piggybacks off of an existing MachineFunctionPass, but I wanted to parse the resulting ASM file to compare the assembly code with and without the new pass.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a tool for which you can define an assembly language syntax, and then build custom analyzers.  You analyzers might be simple ("how much space does an instruction take?") or complex ("How many cycles will this isntruction take to execute?" [which depends on the preceding sequence of instructions and possibly a sophisticated model of the processor you care about]).

One designed specifically to do that is the [New Jersey Machine Toolkit](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/toolkit/).  It is really designed to build code generators and debuggers.  I suspect it would be good at "instruction byte count".  It isn't clear it is good at more sophisticated analyses.   And I believe it insists you follow *its* syntax style, rather than yours.

One not designed specifically to do that, but good at parsing/analyzing langauges in general is our
[DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

DMS can be given a grammar description for virtually any context free language (that covers most assembly language syntax) and can then parse a specific instance of that grammar (assembly code) into ASTs for further processing.  We've done with with several assembly langauges, including the IBM 370, Motorola's 8 bit CPU line, and a rather peculiar DSP, without trouble.

You can specify an attribute grammar (computation over an AST) to DMS easily.  These are great way to encode analyses that need just local information, such as "How big is this instruction?".   For more complex analysese, you'll need a processor model that is driven from a series of instructions; passing such a machine model the ASTs for individual instructions would be an easy way to apply a machine model to compute more complex things as "How long does this instruction take?".

Other analyses such as control flow and data flow, are provided in generic form by DMS.  You can use an attribute evaluator to collect local facts ("control-next for this instruction is...", "data from this instruction flows to,...") and feed them to the flow analyzers to compute global flow facts ("if I execute this instruction, what other instructions might be executed downstream?"..)

You do have to configure DMS for your particular (assembly) language.  It is *designed* to be configured for tasks like these.

Yes, you can likely code all this in Python; after all, its a Turing machine. But likely not nearly as easily.

An additional benefit: DMS is willing to apply *transformations* to your code, based on your analyses. So you could implement your optimizer with it, too.  After all, you need to connect the analysis indication the optimization is safe, to the actual optimization steps.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the fascinating TechTalk. I think DMS might be overkill for my particular situation, but the concept itself is very interesting. How steep is the learning curve when using DMS?

Comment: DMS is a complex system because it deals with complicated artifacts, and does some pretty complex things (flow analysis on 25 million lines of C code requires some pretty amazing machinery).   You can learn the basics in a week; check out http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html for a quick tour of the basics.  It probably takes 6-12 months to become *good* at using DMS; think of the learning curve to become good at using C++.   That might not be the right way to think about DMS; the real question is, how long would it take to do the same task without?

Comment: it doesn't look like it's free of charge though, therefore it might not be suitable for personal projects / free-software projects. Or am I mistaking and just missed the "download" link ? Looks like a cool tool though.

Comment: @Matthieu: The New Jersey Machine Toolkit is open source AFAIK. DMS is a commercial product, and probably not suitable for personl/free-software projects.  But then, if you are going to do something that takes 6-12 months of engineering, it probably isn't a personal project.

Answer (score 2):

I have written many disassemblers, including arm and thumb.  Not production quality but for the purposes of learning the assembler.  For both the ARM and Thumb the ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual) has a nice chart from which you can easily count up data operations from load/store, etc.  maybe an hours worth of work, maybe two.  At least up front, you would end up with data values being counted though.

The other poster may be right, as with the chart I am talking about it should be very simple to write a program to examine the ASCII looking for ldr, str, add, etc.  No need to parse everything if you are interested in memory operations counts, etc.  Of course the downside is that you are likely not going to be able to examine loops.  One function may have a load and store, another may have a load and store but have it wrapped by a loop, causing many more memory operations once executed.

Not knowing what you really are interested in, my guess is you might want to simulate the code and count these sorts of things.  I wrote a thumb simulator (thumbulator) that attempts to do just that.  (and I have used it to compare llvm execution vs gcc execution when it comes to number of instructions executed, fetches, memory operations, etc)  The problem may be that it is thumb only, no ARM no Thumb2.  Thumb2 could be added easier than ARM.  There exists an armulator from arm, which is in the gdb sources among other places.  I cant remember now if it executes thumb2.  My understanding is that when arm was using it would accurately tell you these sorts of statistics.

Comment: You didn't call it a "Thimbleulator"?

Answer (score 1):

You can plug your statistics into LLVM code generator, it's quite flexible and it is already collecting some stats, which could be used as an example.